# SQL Server: auto-generated custom format sequence number

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, procedure

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2014. In our requirement, custom formatted sequence number is include.

The sequence number format is **`CAT-YYYY-MM-NNNNNN`**. Sample data:

```
CAT-2016-10-000001
CAT-2016-10-000002
                 .
                 .
                 .
CAT-2016-10-999999
```

I don't want to use **GUID** or any other and I want to work with a procedure or function.

So, I am trying with this:

```
CREATE TABLE [category]
(
    [id] int NOT NULL UNIQUE IDENTITY,
    [category_no] nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    [category_name] nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([id])
);

CREATE FUNCTION generate_category_no() 
RETURNS CHAR(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @category_no CHAR(20) 
    SET @category_no = (SELECT MAX(category_no) FROM category) 

    IF @category_no IS NULL
         SET @category_no = 'CAT-' + YEAR(getDate()) + '-' + MONTH(getDate()) + '-000001' 

    DECLARE @no int 
    SET @no = RIGHT(@category_no,6) + 1 

    RETURN 'CAT-' + YEAR(getDate()) + '-' + MONTH(getDate()) + '-' + right('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@no),6) 
END
GO

ALTER TABLE category DROP COLUMN category_no;
ALTER TABLE category ADD category_no AS dbo.generate_category_no();

INSERT INTO category (category_name) 
VALUES ('BMW'), ('JAGUAR');
```

When I run the above SQL in step-by-step, it is OK. It shown no error. But when I run the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM category;
```

it shows the following error:

> Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

I don't know how to solve this one. And even I don't know my function has worked or not. I referenced from internet for this function.

**ADDED**

I need to reset sequence no for every month. Eg. for next month, no should be as follow:

```
CAT-2016-11-000001
```

Please, enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if two sessions run (SELECT MAX(category_no) FROM category)  at the same time?  Who gets the +1 value?

Comment: You are getting error on selecting data from table or while executing the function or while creating the function ? Are there any triggers associated with table ?

Comment: No, there is no trigger in db. Only this function.

Comment: There is infinity loop happens here, so the SQL Server engine is preventing this via setting the maxamum of nesting level equals 32.

The infinity loop is happening via calling select * from category that call your function that select from the same table .. so on.

if you select * from category where 1= 2. there is no error, and there is no data too :) , but when selecting data, the infinity loop is happening.

Comment: No, when I run the sql `Select id, category_name, category_no From category Where id < 3;`, it shown the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. My **Function** look like as follow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_category_no() 
RETURNS CHAR(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @category_no CHAR(20) 
    SET @category_no = (SELECT MAX(category_no) FROM category WHERE category_no LIKE CONCAT('CAT-', YEAR(getDate()), '-', MONTH(getDate()), '-%')) 
    IF @category_no is null SET @category_no = CONCAT('CAT-', YEAR(getDate()), '-', MONTH(getDate()), '-000000')
    DECLARE @no INT 
    SET @no = RIGHT(@category_no,6) + 1 
    RETURN CONCAT('CAT-', YEAR(getDate()), '-', MONTH(getDate()), '-', RIGHT('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@no),6))
END
GO
```

And I **insert** data as follow:

```
INSERT INTO category (category_no, category_name) VALUES (dbo.generate_category_no(),'BMW');
INSERT INTO category (category_no, category_name) VALUES (dbo.generate_category_no(),'JAGUAR');
```

One things is that **We can call function from INSERT query**.

So, when I run the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM category;
```

It give the result as shown in below.

```
+---+--------------------+--------------+
|id |category_no         |category_name |
+---+--------------------+--------------+
| 1 |CAT-2016-10-000001  | BMW          |
| 2 |CAT-2016-10-000002  | JAGUAR       |
+---+--------------------+--------------+
```

Thanks everybody for helping me. Thanks!!!

Comment: can it be handle concurrency?

Comment: When 100 records are sent simultaneously for inset in table, does this function manage concurrency?  i have this problem like u

Comment: For me, it is ok till now. I also tested for more than 1000 records, it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your function as below

```
ALTER TABLE category DROP COLUMN category_no;

alter FUNCTION dbo.generate_category_no( @id int) 
RETURNS CHAR(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 

    RETURN 'CAT-' + cast(YEAR(getDate()) as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(MONTH(getDate()) as varchar(10))+ '-' + right('00000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@id),6) 
END



ALTER TABLE category ADD category_no AS dbo.generate_category_no(id);

INSERT INTO category
(category_name) 
VALUES 
('BMW13'),
('JAGUAR');
```

SELECT * FROM category will give the below result.

```
1   BMW     CAT-2016-10-000001  
2   JAGUAR  CAT-2016-10-000002  
3   BMW1    CAT-2016-10-000003  
4   BMW13   CAT-2016-10-000004
```

Comment: Good solution , just Note: you linked the category_no with id, so if there is a gap within identity , the category_no also has the same scope of gap. is it an issue on asker business or not ?

Comment: Then try below query                                                                           select id,category_name,'CAT-2016-10-00000'+cast(row_number() over(order by id) as varchar(10)) as catid from category

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

To initialize your new field:

```
ALTER TABLE category DROP COLUMN category_no;
ALTER TABLE category ADD category_no CHAR(20)

UPDATE category set category_no = dbo.generate_category_no()
```

For other insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[category_i] 
ON  [dbo].[category]
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE category
    SET category_no = dbo.generate_category_no()
    FROM inserted
    WHERE category.pk = inserted.pk
END
```

But you can try to use `SEQUENCE` feature, available on Sql Server by 2012 version

About `SEQUENCE` you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/jj714731.aspx)

Comment: I just upvote your answer, because trigger is not my aim. And your answer is right in one way. But, I just want to use function in column.  Now, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: @NaingWinHtun: Hi dear, thank you for your upvote. Obviously you accept the answer accomplish your aim, so it's right yo have accepted yours ;) Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Biggest flaw in your function is it will not work for **Batch Insert's**

Since you have `ID` auto generated, here is a easier way to do this

```
category_no AS Concat('CAT-', Year(Getdate()), '-', Month(Getdate()), '-', RIGHT(Concat('00000', id), 6))
```

**Demo**

```
CREATE TABLE #seq
  (
     id   INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     name VARCHAR(10),
     category_no AS Concat('CAT-', Year(Getdate()), '-', Month(Getdate()), '-', RIGHT(Concat('00000', id), 6))
  )

INSERT INTO #seq
            (name)
VALUES      ('val')
```

**Result :**

```
id  name    category_no
--  ----    -----------
1   val     CAT-2016-10-000001
```